# TMVar, but without the buffer?

Tags: multithreading, haskell, stm

I'm trying to do communication between Haskell lightweight threads. Threads want to send each other messages for communication and synchronisation.

I was originally using `TMVar` for this, but I've just realised that the semantics are wrong: a `TMVar` will store one message in it internally, so positing a message to an empty `TMVar` won't block. It'll only block if you post a message to a *full* `TMVar`.

Can anyone suggest a similar `STM` IPC construct which:

- will cause all writes to block until the message is consumed;
- will cause all reads to block until a message is provided?

i.e. a zero-length pipe would be ideal; but I don't think `BoundedChan` would be happy if I gave it a capacity of 0. (Also, it's not `STM`.)

Comment: What's your outer problem? Why would you want this?

Comment: Would you be willing to consider a solution which makes the send be an `IO` action rather than an `STM` one (but receiving is still an `STM` action)? What about vice versa (send is an `STM` action but receive is an `IO` action)?

Comment: I need to be able to combine actions (in order to be able to read from several of these things at once and unblock as soon as the first thing becomes readable). AFAIK this can only be done with `STM`.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner: in fact, yes. See below.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your problem correctly, I don't think you can, since the transactional guarantees mean that transaction A can't read from transaction B's write until transaction B is committed, at which point it can no longer block.

`TMVar` is the closest you're going to get if you're using STM. With IO, you may be able to build a structure which only completes a write when a reader is available (this structure may already exist, but I'm not aware of it).

Comment: In other systems, I'd build this by bolting together semaphores. I'd need to sit down and think this through properly, but a write has two blocking stages (wait for empty, then post message, then wait for empty again) while a read just has one (wait for full, then read message). So it probably doesn't make sense for the write to be a single transaction, even though that loses me composability. The `TMVar` source code is admirably simple; I might try adding a 'block until empty' action. If I try to do something impossible inside a transaction, will `STM` error out or just deadlock?

Comment: Both: STM errors out if it deadlocks. You can't add a "block until empty" inside the same transaction as a "put", since it'll just deadlock because the transaction will never get committed (and also because STM has no concept of blocking).

Comment: You, I'd need to do it in two transactions and rely on higher-level stuff to keep it consistent. ...I'm astonished such a thing doesn't already exist; basically what I want is Linda. Surely someone's done this?

Comment: If you make it two transactions it's no longer composable and you lose STM's transactional guarantees. It would be easier and more sensible to implement this in IO with an `MVar`.

Comment: Yep, I'll have to change my design. The only thing I need composability for is to wait for changes on multiple channels; given that the wait-until-consumed stage only happens after one channel has become writeable, that can happen in a different transaction. I haven't found a way to compose MVars.

Comment: No, dammit, that won't work. If the channel fills up again soon enough after the consumer removes the value, the producer won't notice it's empty and so won't wake up. (Which is likely to happen if the consumer replies back on the same channel.) This is why I hate building IPC systems.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you're so certain you can't use an `MVar`.

Comment: How do I block on multiple MVars?

Comment: `TMVar`, rather, I understand why you can't use `MVar`.

Comment: So I wrote an implementation using three `TSem`s and a `TVar`. Some very very basic testing shows it _appears_ to work, but it's not like it's being heavily used right now. I'll post it as an answer in a few days once I know it's a bit more reliable. Thank-you for the conversation --- it was really useful in figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to reformulate the two requirements:

> - will cause all writes to block until the message is consumed;
> - will cause all reads to block until a message is provided.

The problem is with terms *block* and *consumed/provided*. With STM there is no notion of *block*, there is just [`retry`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/GHC-Conc-Sync.html#v:retry), which has a different semantics: It restarts the current transaction - it doesn't wait until something happens (this could cause deadlocks). So we can't say "block until ...", we can only say something like "the transaction succeeds only when ...".

Similarly, what does "until a message is consumed/provided" mean? Since transactions are atomic, it can only be "until the transaction that consumed/provided a message succeeded".

So let's try to reformulate:

> - will cause all writes to retry until a transaction that consumes the message succeeds;
> - will cause all reads to retry until a transaction that provides a message succeeds.

But now the first point doesn't make sense: If a write retries, there is no message to be consumed, the transaction didn't pause, it's been discarded and started over - possibly producing a different message!

In other words: Any data can ever leave a STM transaction only when it succeeds (completes). This is by design - the transactions are always *atomic* from the point of view of the outside world / other transactions - you can never observe results of only a part of a transaction. You can never observe two transactions interacting.

So a 0-length queue is a bad analogy - it will never allow to pass any data though. At the end of any transaction, it'll have to have to be empty, so no data will ever pass through.

Nevertheless I believe it'll be possible to reformulate the requirements according to your goals and subsequently find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You say you would be happy with one side or the other being in `IO` rather than `STM`. So then it is not too hard to code this up. Let's start with the version that has receiving in `IO`. To make this happen, the receiver will have to initiate the handshake.

```
type SynchronousVar a = TChan (TMVar a)

send :: SynchronousVar a -> a -> STM a
receive :: SynchronousVar a -> IO a

send svar a = do
    tmvar <- readTChan svar
    putTMVar tmvar a

receive svar = do
    tmvar <- newEmptyTMVarIO
    atomically $ writeTChan svar tmvar
    atomically $ takeTMVar tmvar
```

A similar protocol can be written that has sending start the handshake.

```
type SynchronousVar a = TChan (a, TMVar ())

send :: SynchronousVar a -> a -> IO a
receive :: SynchronousVar a -> STM a

send svar a = do
    tmvar <- newEmptyTMVarIO
    atomically $ writeTChan svar (a, tmvar)
    atomically $ takeTMVar tmvar

receive svar = do
    (a, tmvar) <- readTChan svar
    putTMvar tmvar ()
    return a
```

Probably, if you really need synchronous communication, this is because you want two-way communication (i.e. the action that's running in `IO` wants to know something about the thread it's synchronizing with). It is not hard to extend the above protocol to pass off a tad more information about the synchronization (by adding it to the one-tuple in the former case or to the `TMVar` in the latter case).